# Adding JFreeChart to Maven in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, user-interface, jfreechart

I'm trying add `JFreeChart` to maven to create a piechart in a project.
However, I coudn't do that in eclipse or intellij idea. What do I have to do?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.erkanakin.odev1</groupId>
<artifactId>Odev1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Odev1</name>
<description>bil211</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>/jfreechart</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding referenced eclipse projects to maven dependancies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136362/adding-referenced-eclipse-projects-to-maven-dependancies)

Comment: You added wrong artifactId for this libs. It should be <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId> instead of <artifactId>/jfreechart</artifactId>

Answer (score 3):

[`JFreeChart`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) version 1.0.19 is current. This [repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfree/jfreechart/1.0.19) suggests the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Subsequent versions may be found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfree/jfreechart).